# Removing edge without loosing faces

Tags: edges

Apologies noob here, I would like to remove the following edge:

[image]

But if I select the edge and press x -> dissolve edge the result is:

[image]

If instead I delete the edge wuth x -> Edges the mesh loose its face(s):

[image]

I would like to remove the edge and keeping the faces (or join them into one if this is not possible). How I do that in Blender?

Comment: you can delete the edge then select all and fill with F but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hi again :-) basically I have an algorithm that needs a polygon mesh to work correctly, thus I need to remove any internal edgs that are not part of the polygon perimeter.

Comment: Limited dissolve is one of the delete option menu (X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "limited dissolve", but I agree with moonboots, why to dissolve that edge?